# Apache2 redirect mysite.com/owncloud to another internal server with the data

Tags: apache2, proxy

I want to have a website with OwnCloud on another server. The website is hosted on 192.168.0.100 but OwnCloud is on 192.168.0.200.

How can I set it up so that everywhere I am, I can use OwnCloud with a link like: owncloud.mysite.com or mysite.com/owncloud? Is it possible to create this. How? I tried with proxy pass, but it doesn't work (I think I did something wrong). The subdomain is not created.

This is what I want:

[image: that]

Comment: Is there a requirement for Apache as the proxy?  Can you live without the proxy? Could you use something like NGINX instead? Does it require SSL? Do you have one or two external IP addresses? Do you want the OwnCloud server accessible both with and without the redirect?  A lot of questions need answering, before we can help I think.

Comment: No the proxy (with virtualhost) have no requirements. Yes but why can i do that without a proxy (how can i access it if i am outside of my local network), i don't know how to use NGINX. No ssl is not required. I have just one external IP. Both or just one with the domain like that owncloud.mysite.com or mysite.com/owncloud. I can create it too with a php or something like that (when i can how can i create a subdomain).Thanks for the help ^^ @ThatGuy

Comment: Let me do some testing, I'll see if I can come up with a simple working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

I've attempted multiple solutions for OwnCloud, but cannot get passed the ProxyPass stage.  Apparently, there are a lot of people who want to use Apache as a Reverse Proxy, and are having issues with the .htaccess and config of OwnCloud.

I cannot for the life of me find a fix, as the vast majority of Reverse Proxy servers are NGINX.

What I'm posting here, is only enough to get the Apache server to Proxy the OwnCloud server.  There are errors and config problems, but anything after that point will have to be resolved in the OwnCloud configuration, or by asking someone who is more familiar with how OwnCloud works.

Sorry I can't provide any more information.  This is kind of my limit, as I'm not entirely sure how OwnCloud works, and issues surrounding its Reverse Proxying.

**Steps**

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get -y upgrade`
3. `sudo apt-get -y install apache2`
4. `sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_html proxy_http proxy_ajp deflate headers proxy_balancer proxy_connect rewrite`
5. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/owncloud.conf`

Paste:

```
Alias /owncloud "http://192.168.1.200:80/owncloud"
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /owncloud http://192.168.20.200:80/owncloud/
  ProxyPassReverse /owncloud http://192.168.20.200:80/owncloud/
```

6. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. `sudo a2enconf owncloud`
8. `sudo systemctl reload apache2`

If you browse to http://192.168.20.100/owncloud you should now see your OwnCloud installation.

The rest of the configuration is now done in `/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php`

**Reference Material**

[Config.php Parameters](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html)

[Reverse Proxy Configuration](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/reverse_proxy_configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by proxying via a URL (example.com for the below) to a LAN IP on a different box at 192.168.0.x

On the Apache Reverse proxy add the below to the SSL config:

```
rewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/owncloud$ https://example.com/owncloud/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "https://example.com/owncloud/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/owncloud
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /owncloud$1 [R=301,L]
<Location /owncloud/>
    ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.x/owncloud/" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30 keepalive=on
    ProxyPassReverse "http://192.168.0.x/owncloud/"
</Location>
```

This worked for the most part, but caused the login page to give an error.

This is solved by adding the below to the owncloud config:

```
'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
'overwritehost' => 'example.com',
```

Now everything (including Owncloud Apps) works well via the Apache Proxy

Comment: The SSL config is the ssl.config file, and the owncloud  config is the httpd.conf file. Is it that way? Please name the configs by their correct file-names in your post.